# check if the variable is signed using is_signed

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to check if the variable is signed. I've found a class template whose name is [is_signed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) but I cannot use it since I'm new for C++. How can I check that the variable is signed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    // the following short initialization is on purpose
    short price {10u};
    std::cout << std::is_signed<price>::value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `is_signed` is for *types* not for variables. `std::cout << std::is_signed<short>::value << '\n';`

Comment: @john thanks for the point, but what about for my intention?

Comment: "I want to check if the variable is signed." - you know if it signed, because you defined it.

Comment: try`is_signed<decltype(price)>`

Comment: If you want to know if a signed type is positive or negative, compare it against zero. `if( price < 0 ) { std::cout << "price is negative\n"; }`

Comment: @concurrencyboy And what is your intention? What do want to achieve?

Comment: The variable is always signed because it's a `short`. It doesn't matter that you initialized it from an unsigned literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`is_signed` - like many other of these structs is a way to perform a check on a **type** - but not on a **variable**. you can use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to get the underlying type of your variables.

```
std::cout << std::is_signed<decltype(price)>::value << '\n'; //-> 1
```

Also - `is_signed` is defined in `<type_traits>` and not `<cmath>`.

---

as already mentioned in the comments; if your intention is to simply see if the variable **is positive or negative** you won't need any library utilities.

To get *that* information use `price > 0` or `price < 0` respectively. These are, of course, runtime only operations.

Comment: C++14 way is a bit simpler: cout<<std::is_signed<decltype(price)>{}();

Comment: @Red.Wave and the C++17 way is simpler: `cout << std::is_signed_v<decltype(price)>;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau mere "simpler" is wrong. Should've been "even simpler".

Answer (score 1):

Arguments to Class Templates must be types.
If you have a variable and you wan to get it's type, you can use decltype:

```
std::cout << std::is_signed<decltype (price)>::value << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

the implementation of `is_signed` can be something like

```
template<bool IsArithmetic, typename T> struct is_signed_impl : bool_constant<T(-1) < T(0)>
    {};

template<typename T> struct is_signed_impl<false, T> : false_type
    {};

template<typename T> struct is_signed
        : is_signed_impl<is_arithmetic_v<T>, T>
    {};
```

the template variable `T` in `is_signed<T>` is finally used in `T(-1) < T(0)`, which is for casting. If T is a non-type argument like`price`, the cast is not well-formed.